# Can express-form validate an input type of 'file' to be required?

Tags: validation, node.js, express

I'm using `express-form` https://github.com/dandean/express-form

Does it have the ability to validate an input of the type `file`? I specifically want to `require` that someone upload a file.

EDIT for Linus :)

I've tried:
`field("pdf").required("pdf", "You must select a file to upload.")`

The problem is that this is looking for `req.body.pdf` not `req.files.pdf`, so it always thinks the validation fails.

**EDIT / WORKING CODE: What I did to get it to work based on Linus' answer.**

Not only did I need to configure the `dataSources` param, I also needed to check the field's `size` property as just doing a `required` on the field isn't good enough because even if a file input is empty, it still exists (meta data, etc). So instead, I do a custom validation function that makes sure `pdf.size` is greater than 0. In my code, I also check to see if I have a `title`. I left that here in case anyone was wondering how to string together multiple validations.

```
var form = require('express-form')
  .configure({dataSources: ['body', 'files', 'query', 'params']});

form(
  field("pdf.size").custom(function(value) {
    if (value <= "0") {
      throw new Error("You must select a file to upload.");
    }
  })
 , field("title").trim().required("title", "Please enter a title for your PDF."))
```

Comment: @LinusGThiel Good point, edit added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the README](https://github.com/dandean/express-form):

> Express Form has various configuration options, but aims for sensible defaults for a typical Express application.
>
> ...
>
> dataSources (Array): An array of Express request properties to use as data sources when filtering and validating data. Default: `["body", "query", "params"]`.

So something along these lines should do the trick:

```
var form = require('express-form')
           .configure({dataSources: ['body', 'files', 'query', 'params']});
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed that. One thing to add. I'll add an edit to my original question showing what I had to do to get it to work.